# How to scrape a new page using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I tried to scrape Reddit using puppeteer and Node.js. There is my code, where I:

1. open a page for Reddit's main page,
2. Get all posts.
3. For each post I get the link to its content page.
4. Open a new page for each content page.
5. Scrape each content page.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const self = {
  browser: null,
  page: null,

  initialize: async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
    });
    page = await browser.newPage();

    // Go to the index page of Reddit
    await page.goto("https://old.reddit.com/", { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });
  },

  getResults: async () => {
    let platform = "Reddit";

    // Get all posts on the main page of Reddit.
    let mentions = await page.$$('#siteTable > div[class *= "thing"]');
    let results = [];

    // For each post:
    for (let mention of mentions) {
      let content = "";

      // I get the link to its content page.
      let content_URL = await mention.$eval(
        'p[class="title"] > a[class*="title"]',
        (node) => node.getAttribute("href").trim()
      );

      // if it is a inner link:
      if (content_URL.substr(0, 3) === "/r/") {

        // Create a new page to open that content page. 
        let contentPage = await browser.newPage();
        await contentPage.goto("https://old.reddit.com" + content_URL, {
          waitUntil: "networkidle0",
        });

        // Get the first paragraph of this content page.
        content = await contentPage.evaluate((contentPage) => {
          
          // Here is where the error occurred: 
          // Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined
          let firstParagraph = contentPage.querySelector(
            'div[class*="usertext-body"] > p'
          );

          if (firstParagraph != null) {
            return firstParagraph.innerText.trim();
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        });
      }

      results.push({
        title,
        content,
        image,
        date,
        popularity,
        platform,
      });
    }

    return results;
  },
};

module.exports = self;
```

But an error occurred: `Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined`.

Could anyone point out where I did wrong plz?

Thanks!

Comment: `contentPage` is undefined.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But I did define it in `let contentPage = await browser.newPage();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`page.evaluate` basically executes code in the context of the browser. IE: the same stuff you would put into the browser developer console to get the same result. So in this context, you would want to use `document.querySelector()` instead of a reference to `contentPage` which isn't defined:

```
let firstParagraph = document.querySelector(
  'div[class*="usertext-body"] > p'
);
```